# How to create a hash function for use with array of integers

Tags: arrays, c, hash

I am studying about hash tables and hashing functions and trying to create my own function for hashing an array of integers

I found two useful resources the [first one](https://www.journaldev.com/35238/hash-table-in-c-plus-plus) explains how to make a hash function for an array of chars in c++ but my goal is to use pure c and create one for an array of integers, the [second one](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eoz/hash.html) how three popular and well-known hash functions created by other people

Now for my purpose I managed to create this hash function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CAP 100000

unsigned long hash_function(int *arr , int arrSize)
{
    unsigned long i = 65599; // 65599 is a prime number 
    for (int j =0; j < arrSize; j++)
        i = (arr[j] << 2) + (i<<8) -i;
    return i % CAP;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {-1, 0 ,1}; // sum of numbers is 0
    int nums2[] = {1,0,-1}; // sum of numbers is 0
    int nums3[] = {-1,1,2,-2};// sum of numbers is 0
    int nums4[] = {0,1,-1}; // sum of numbers is 0


    unsigned long x = hash_function(nums, sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]));
    unsigned long y = hash_function(nums2, sizeof(nums2)/sizeof(nums2[0]));
    unsigned long z = hash_function(nums3, sizeof(nums3)/sizeof(nums3[0]));
    unsigned long n = hash_function(nums4, sizeof(nums4)/sizeof(nums4[0]));



    printf("Result of hashing arrays\nnums: [%ld]\nnums2: [%ld]\nnums3: [%ld]\nnums4: [%ld]  \n",x,y,z,n);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I tell if this is a working hash function or if it is good enough to use for any small project?

Comment: To evaluate a hash function, we'd need to know what it's used for. For example, cryptography? No, it is not good enough. If you need a hash function for production purposes, don't write your own; use an existing one such as provided by [Glib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.HashTable.html).

Comment: My first criticism would be: function result depends on the size of `long` (as `CAP` is not a power of 2), so may vary between processor architectures or compilers.

Comment: @Schwern I am trying to make my own I am fully aware of the fact that the end result won't be as good as any other solutions such as Glib but I am more interested in the learning process, and why is it not good enough for cryptography what is the reason that makes you say so

Comment: @RuudHelderman as I told Schwern I am more about learning the concepts I am not trying to create a better Glib I just want to have a full understanding of how to make a proper hashing function so you can assume that I  will be using one type of hardware

Comment: @manuel Computers are so powerful and the stakes are so high that cryptographic attacks have gotten crazy good. Any crypto you or I could write will have many fundamental flaws. Even experts developing crypto require [many rounds of public scrutiny by other experts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_hash_function_competition) before an algorithm can be considered secure. You won't learn much from writing your own because there's so much you don't know you don't know about crypto. Instead, study existing cryptographic hash functions and how they were broken.

Comment: @manuel Even for non-cryptographic purposes, [a bad hash function can be a security issue](https://www.securityweek.com/hash-table-collision-attacks-could-trigger-ddos-massive-scale). I would suggest reading existing hash implementations such as [glib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/glib/ghash.c#L438) or [ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6e65e04186edbf2b5be88cd30268d455a9c6fec5/hash.c#L1092). They're pretty easy to follow.